# Website load/response time (Images)

Tags: html, image

So, I've made my first website, but I've run into a sort of a problem. In the website, [here](http://aloezante.gr), I have photos. Now, the image dimensions are fairly large, and I would like to keep it that way, so they would be resized to fit as many screen sizes as possible. Now, as you can see in the site, I have uploaded my pictures to imgur. That was before I had a server to work with, for testing purposes. Will uploading the pictures to my server improve load time of the photos?

Also, on a side note, what are the advantages of uploading them to a server? (one with limited space, mind you. This is mainly why I am asking.)
Would uploading plugins, like say, Jquery, to the server, instead of using, say, `<script src="CDN of choice" />` and `<link>` for css, improve initial load time?

My apologies if this is a stupid question, but bare in mind that I am new to this. If you'd like to, any other critique on the site would be appreciated.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a CDN service will usually give better loading times. And for common resources, like a JS library, there is the extra benefit that the client may have already requested that library and has it cached from a visit to another site that shared the same CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest improvement you can get here is by compressing your images. When saving in photoshop, select save for the web, and to further decrease the file size. Use something like https://tinyjpg.com/ . I was able to compress one of your images that was 2.5mb to 947kb. Do this for all your images and you won't have to worry about CDN and load time. Your javascript and css files are much much smaller than your images and I doubt you will get any real load time improvement by optimizing them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Uploading your image (and/or other assets) to your server. Although it makes sense at first, but will make you have the following problems:

1. You lose lots of your allocated bandwidth, the more people visiting your website.
2. The speed of yourwebsite for your visitors will depend on your server and how far they are from it.

For the second issue, I would always suggest using CDN relay like cloudflare or cloudfront. it makes the load time much faster and also saves the bandwidth.

Also, if bandwidth and spare id a real problem, you should either consider using a better host, or simply use something like Amazon s3 to host your static files.

Comment: The server does have, or at least says it has, unlimited traffic, but it's limited to 500MB of disk space.

Comment: In such case I would use s3. Also if your website is a static one (no php, rails, python ..etc), why don't you consider hosting it on github pages for free? they have CDN overlay as well.

Comment: So the only way to improve image load time is scaling them down? I'd like to avoid it, but it can be done fairly easily...

I'll look into s3, thanks.

Comment: Maybe I should've looked into that earlier, but now it's too late for that. We've already rented a server for 2 years.